cookies are not saved in reverse proxies
I add cookies to every query. I unloaded them from my browser and they are valid for the site. I set them in each request, but I still get a page with an unauthorized account. I also tried not uploading my cookies, but saving them from the responses and adding them to the requests. I.e. if I authorize 1 time in reverse proxy, they should return an authorized page to everyone. But it didn't work for me
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
    "net/url"
    "os"
    
    "time"
)

func main() {

    cookies_byte, err := os.ReadFile("cookies.json")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    x := []struct {
        Name string `json:"name"`
        Value string `json:"value"`
        Domain string `json:"domain"`
        Path string `json:"path"`
        Secure bool `json:"secure"`
        HttpOnly bool `json:"httpOnly"`
        SameSite string `json:"sameSite"`
        ExpirationDate float64 `json:"expirationDate"`
    }{}

    err = json.Unmarshal(cookies_byte, &x)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    cookies := []*http.Cookie{}

    for _, el := range x {
        cookies = append(cookies, &http.Cookie{
            Name:   el.Name,
            Value: el.Value,
            Domain: el.Domain,
            Path: el.Path,
            Secure: el.Secure,
            HttpOnly: el.HttpOnly,
            SameSite: func ()  http.SameSite{
                if el.SameSite == "no_restriction"{
                    return http.SameSiteNoneMode
                }else if el.SameSite == "lax"{
                    return http.SameSiteLaxMode
                }
                return http.SameSiteDefaultMode
            }(),
            Expires: time.Unix(int64(el.ExpirationDate), 0),
        })
    }
    
    target, err := url.Parse("https://quillbot.com/")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(target)

    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        r.Host = target.Host
        for _, el := range cookies {
            r.AddCookie(el)
        }
        
        log.Printf("\nURL: %s\nSocket: %s\nUsergent: %s\n", r.URL.Path, r.RemoteAddr, r.UserAgent())

        proxy.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        cookies = r.Cookies()
    })

    if http.ListenAndServe(":8090", nil) != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

reverse proxies work with unauthorized site

Use cookies = r.Cookies() to get the request cookie. The response cookie needs to be get and parsed from w.Header().Get("Set-Cookie").
